# I would like to improve my JavaScript condition code

Tags: javascript

Please bear with me because I am new to JavaScript and I was given this code to try to improve it so any input is helpful. I was told to list some concerns or problems that you see with the code. So far I see that:

Using the double equal equality operator to compare an object against a string may not be the best solution

**if typeof data !=='object'**

Also please assume that assume **PeopleFactory** is defined globally

Feel free to pick apart the code. It would be very helpful.
Thanks

```
var Person_D = function Person_D(name) {
  //assume PeopleFactory is defined globally
  //getDetailsAsync returns either null or a record with specific name.
  PeopleFactory.getDetailsAsync(name, function(data) {
    if (typeof data !== 'object') {
      throw new Error('No record found for this individual.');
    }

    this.name = data.name;
    this.age = data.age || 'No age data available.';
    this.eyeColor = data.eyeColor || "This individual's eye color data is not listed.";
    this.height = data.size.height || "No height specified.";

  });

  return this;

}

var personD = new Person_D('Jana');

console.log(personD.name);
```

Comment: `typeof data` is not an object. Is this an interview question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (if anywhere). Please read their [Asking](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) guidelines before posting it there.

Comment: What is your problem with using typeof?

Comment: If data returns either a valid name or NULL, just check for null? `if (data == NULL)`

Comment: the log() doesn't work because the async data fetching, does that matter? `this.name` is defined by the callback...

Comment: @TiesonT. Unfortunately code that is [not written by the asker](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-questions-are-suitable-for-migration-to-code-review-and-how-does-the-proce/1689#1689) is off-topic for code-review. The best reason to close is probably "too broad" since it asks to "improve" the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question in its current state is too broad to "answer", however there are at least 3 bugs in the code that will cause errors in all cases.

1. The code loads the properties of `Person_D` through `PeopleFactory.getDetailsAsync`, which is asynchronous, but access `personD.name` synchronously.
2. The code uses `this` to assign properties in a callback so `this` is no longer referencing the `Person_D` object.
3. `if(typeof data !=='object')` will actually always result in `true` because `typeof null` and `typeof new Object()` both result in `"object"`. Use `=== null` instead.

Possible fix (making no assumptions on how the code *should* work, just making it work as probably intended with correct outputs):

```
var Person_D = function Person_D(name) {
  var self = this;
  //assume PeopleFactory is defined globally
  //getDetailsAsync returns either null or a record with specific name.
  PeopleFactory.getDetailsAsync(name, function(data) {
    if (data === null) {
      throw new Error('No record found for this individual.');
    }

    self.name = data.name;
    self.age = data.age || 'No age data available.';
    self.eyeColor = data.eyeColor || "This individual's eye color data is not listed.";
    self.height = data.size.height || "No height specified.";
    console.log(self.name);
  });

  return this;
}

var personD = new Person_D('Jana');
```

Comment: `To add: if(typeof data !=='object') is completely valid js and is actually the best way to do a type comparison.` no, it's not the best: `typeof null` will also give you `"object"` yet I doubt you'd consider it valid.

Comment: @vlaz Hmm good catch, I forgot about that quirk probably because I never encountered a use case for strict type checking against null. Will edit it out.